# Microsoft Access does not print all data shown in the preview

Tags: windows, printing, microsoft-access

We are using Microsoft Access and HP printers.

Some reports created in Access show up all data which should be printed in the preview, but when it comes to printing, there data missing on the paper!

I tried to change the driver for one printer and the font weight from bold to normal to force data to be printed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
This is how it is solved:

Printer Properties... - Advanced - Print Processor (left the same) - Default data type - select (RAW)

Answer (score 0):

If the "HP printers" are inkjet I would first check the ink cartridges, perhaps one color is empty and the missing data are in that color.

Then I would check the printer dialogue preference settings, maybe the print driver is converting color to monochrome and there is some threshold setting in the driver, perhaps there is a "high quality" option you can try.

I would then update the printer drivers

finally I'd try printing to PDF (using any of the many tools that provide for this) or print to plain text file as a diagnosis step.

Comment: hi! well those printers are laser products!